# sql cannot insert same customer ID into shopping cart

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, shopping-cart

Im asking for direction.
I have a .sql file of tables - customer, product and shopping cart.  The shopping cart has the customerID and productID both auto incremented and both as the primary keys.  I INSERTed a record into the shopping cart for a specific customerID, specific productID with a quantity of 1.  I INSERTed another record into the shopping cart for the same customer.
When trying to import into phpMyAdmin, I get an error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'PRIMARY'
How do I add more than one record to the shopping cart with the same customerID?

```
CREATE TABLE Shopping_Cart(
  CustID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ProdID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  Quantity INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(CustID, ProdID));

INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("BostockG12345A", "DULL12275226", 2);
INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("BostockG12345A", "jPET1224108", 1);
```

Thank you all.  I will change it from an integer to VARCHAR when I get home.  I created the table before I assigned IDs.  But that leads me to another question.
For the shopping cart I made up the CustID and ProdID even though they are a auto_increment in the Customer table and Product table.  Im getting a little confused with which comes first, the chicken or the egg (the auto_increments CustID (and ProdID) or the INSERTs CustID (or ProdID).  How do I know what the auto_increment ID number is for the shopping carts INSERT if its all in the same file?  Should I do a query for the ID of the customer whose name is Bostock and the ID of that specific product, then do the INSERT?

Comment: You cannot insert duplicate values in primary key column.Primary key's will accept only unique values.I assume you have already defined the  tables for customer and products.So define ID column as primary key for Customer and product tables(Parent table) and define the CustID and ProdID in Shopping_Cart table as Foreign key with references to Customer and product tables(Parent table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CustID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, --> Integer
  ProdID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -->Integer

INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("BostockG12345A", "DULL12275226", 2);
INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("BostockG12345A", "jPET1224108", 1);

   Wrong May be :  But you are inserting string data in place of integer
```

Answer (score 0):

`CustID` and `ProdID` are integer values in database, you are inserting strings ("BostockG12345A", "DULL12275226") which mysql tries to convert to numbers. result of conversion is 0, so you end up inserting 2 records with CustId =0 and ProdId =0

Answer (score 0):

Change type of CustID and ProdID column. It will work fine, i have tried. Because your value is not an integer type.